# How do I unit test event handlers (from the event bus) in Vert.x?

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm new to to Vert.x 3 and I'm trying to write a unit test for a simple event handler. Right now, all I'm trying to do is to check that the Verticle under test delegates to the correct component, which is created as a mock using Mockito.

My test code looks something like:

```
@Rule
public final RunTestOnContext vertxRule = new RunTestOnContext();

@Before
public void setUp(TestContext context) {
    vertx = vertxRule.vertx();
    //verticle is set up with mock delegate before deployment
    vertx.deployVerticle(verticle);
}

@After
public void tearDown(TestContext context) {
    vertx.close(context.asyncAssertSuccess());
}

@Test
public void testDelegate(TestContext context) {
    EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();
    Event event = new Event("id", "description")
    eventBus.publish("event.channel", Json.encode(event));

    //Mockito.verify
    verify(delegate).invokeMethod(anyString(), anyString());
}
```

The Veticle contains code similar to the following:

```
private Delegate delegate;

@Override
public void start(Future<Void> future) throws Exception {
    vertx.eventBus().consumer("event.channel", message -> {
        logger.info("received!");
        Event event = Json.decodeValue(message.body().toString(), Event.class);
        delegate.invokeMethod(event.getId(), event.getDescription());
    });
}
```

However, every time I run the test, I always get an error saying the mock is not being called. I am certain that the mock object is being injected properly because if I call it outside of the event bus construct, the test passes. Also, the the code logs the `received!` info, so I'm sure that the test execution reaches that point. I'm just not sure why, at the end of the test, the reports says there were no interactions with the mock object.

Answer (score 4):

The verify is executed before the Mock was called. You should have an async in the test that waits before verifying. Like this:

```
@Test
public void testDelegate(TestContext context) {
    EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();
    Event event = new Event("id", "description")
    Async async = context.async();
    eventBus.publish("event.channel", Json.encode(event) ,done ->async.complete());


    async.await()

    //Mockito.verify
    verify(delegate).invokeMethod(anyString(), anyString());
}
```

Then your verticle must reply to the received message by doing message.reply(...) after calling the mock.

**Edit after your comment about no reply**

I tried the following code that uses a global variable (ugly) for synchronization (note that this is a io.vertx.core.Future):

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class StackTest {

    private Vertx vertx;
    public static Future<String> synchronisation = Future.future();

    @Before
    public void setUp(TestContext context) {
        vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new StackVerticle());
    }

    @Test
    public void testPublish(TestContext context){
        vertx.eventBus().publish("topic","message");
        Async async = context.async();
        synchronisation.setHandler(event -> async.complete());
        async.await();
    }
}
```

And the test verticle (the synchronization.complete must be triggered by your mock):

```
public class StackVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        vertx.eventBus().consumer("topic",received ->{
            System.out.println("received");
            StackTest.synchronisation.complete("done");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need my Verticle to reply though.

Comment: that is a problem. Since eventbus.publish() notifies the consumer asynchronously, the execution continues on your next java statement in the test, which is the Mockito.verify. You must find a way to execute this verify after your delegate was called.